# Duplicates with no answers

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, unanswered-questions

I was trying to flag [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679057/functional-analysis-linearly-independent) as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678963/linearly-independent-linear-functionals), (same question, same asker). But the system would not take the original question because it says it has no upvoted answer.

What is one supposed to do in this situation (a person asks the same question twice)?

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10275/allow-closing-as-duplicate-for-new-questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention, they can close as a duplicate without this restriction.

The cases of a user posting the same question multiple times is actually considered, and the restriction does not apply for posts from the same user. In this case the user did create two different accounts, likely by accident, which is why this does not work.

Comment: Good point. I had not noticed that the two accounts were different! Thanks.