# On duplicate questions

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates

Sometimes I've noticed (specially on older questions), that the duplicate tag often sends a link to a question that indeed is a duplicate, but has no answers or has only suggestions, meanwhile the original one may be even better formulated or answered. Does the duplicate tag only prioritize which question was asked first? If this is the case, maybe it would be nice to select the "best" (maybe via upvotes or answers) possible duplicate in order to make things a little more organized. I apologize if this question is, ironically, a duplicate.

Comment: An older question can be closed as a duplicate of a newer question. See also: [Original post marked as duplicate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16417) (and other posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/16417)).

Comment: Based no what I read [in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841) it seems that duplicate without answers can be only chosen: a) by a moderator; b) if both posts are by the same user; c) on meta. A related post on this meta: [Duplicates with no answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12782). So if you found a posts where the duplicate target has no answers and it is neither of those questions, I am a bit surprised.